# listen tcp 127.0.0.1:9090: bind: address already in use

Tags: systemd

How does one finds which service is using port?

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
# netstat -natpv | grep 9090
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd           
#
```

Please advise.

---

```
# systemctl status cockpit.service 
● cockpit.service - Cockpit Web Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cockpit.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2019-06-10 12:43:51 EDT; 4 days ago
     Docs: man:cockpit-ws(8)
 Main PID: 15922 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 10 12:41:48 X.X.X systemd[1]: Starting Cockpit Web Service...
Jun 10 12:41:48 X.X.X systemd[1]: Started Cockpit Web Service.
Jun 10 12:41:48 X.X.X cockpit-ws[15922]: Using certificate: /etc/cockpit/ws-certs.d/0-self-signed.cert
Jun 10 12:42:05 X.X.X cockpit-session[16311]: pam_ssh_add: Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (/root/.ssh/id_rsa)
Jun 10 12:42:07 X.X.X cockpit-ws[15922]: logged in user session
Jun 10 12:42:07 X.X.X cockpit-ws[15922]: New connection to session from 10.52.208.221
Jun 10 12:42:21 X.X.X cockpit-ws[15922]: WebSocket from 10.52.208.221 for session closed
Jun 10 12:42:36 X.X.X cockpit-ws[15922]: session timed out
# lsof -i :9090
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd   1 root   75u  IPv6 7761202      0t0  TCP *:websm (LISTEN)
#
```

Comment: Could be that `Cockpit` is setup on your system ? https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/linux-system-administration-management-console-cockpit

Comment: run `sudo lsof -i :9090`

Comment: @krisFR I thought so too, but it is not

Comment: @AlexD `lsof` shows me `systemd` (I already knew that)

Comment: So what is your question then?

Comment: grep your systemd configs for Listen directive.

Comment: @AlexD haha) i just stumble upon this too! thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`systemctl list-sockets` should show exact unit name and the related service.

```
LISTEN                          UNIT                            ACTIVATES
[::]:9090                       cockpit.socket                  cockpit@0.service
```

Answer (score 2):

not ideal, but better then nothing:

```
# systemctl | grep listening
dm-event.socket                                                                                       loaded active     listening    Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs
iscsid.socket                                                                                         loaded active     listening    Open-iSCSI iscsid Socket
iscsiuio.socket                                                                                       loaded active     listening    Open-iSCSI iscsiuio Socket
lvm2-lvmpolld.socket                                                                                  loaded active     listening    LVM2 poll daemon socket
systemd-initctl.socket                                                                                loaded active     listening    /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe
systemd-shutdownd.socket                                                                              loaded active     listening    Delayed Shutdown Socket
virtlockd.socket                                                                                      loaded active     listening    Virtual machine lock manager socket
virtlogd.socket                                                                                       loaded active     listening    Virtual machine log manager socket
#
```

in my case it was `cockpit.socket` (not `cockpit.service`)

Answer (score 0):

You cloud either use `ss` or `netstat` for this problem.

```
sudo ss -ntpulo
```

or

```
sudo netstat -ntpul
```

Both show the **Network** `tcp` and `udp` protocols and it's **programs_name** as **long list** and at the end you could `grep` the *stdout* like:

```
sudo ss -ntpulo | grep 9090
```

Also remember `netstat` comes with package called `net-tools` so if it's not found on your system just install:

```
# Ubuntu/debian
sudo apt install net-tools

# centos
yum install net-tools
```

P.S: I like `netstat`, it has nicer output :)